# Trying to run Python script without interrupting Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, python-requests, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob

I am trying to run a Python script from a Rails app. This script can POST progress updates to the Rails server by calling:

```
requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/progress', data={'progress':'10'})
```

I've tried a few methods to get the Rails server to start the Python script and immediately continue with the rest of its work. It needs to be free to respond to the user and to receive the above progress updates.

I've tried:

- In a controller method that also renders a view:

  ```
  system `python3 /path/to/script.py`
  out, err, st = Open3.capture3('python3', 'path/to/script.py')
  ```
- Both of the above in an after_action.
- Both of the above in an active_job.

In every case, as soon as the script is initiated, the server basically hangs, as if it's waiting. The test script I'm using **only** sends one progress update then exits, so it shouldn't be causing a major delay even if the server is waiting for it to finish.

What is going on here, and how can I run the script in background properly so my Rails server is available to respond to it?

Comment: Why does the python script need to be invoked from rails? If its constantly running like a daemon you should instead be able to run it with some sort of runner that keeps processes alive.

Comment: It's not constantly running - Rails is running all the time, and it sometimes needs to run a Python script that may end immediately or take some time to finish.

Comment: You might want to see the notes on `after_action` - the callback is placed after the controller method finishes but before the response is sent. What you most likely need is a separate job.

Comment: I've tried active_job with Sidekiq - so far, it's producing the problems I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveJob should work. Try this:

1. in the console generate a new Job
   `rails g job SlowPython`
2. move your slow python script into `app/jobs/script.py`
3. open the new file in `app/jobs/slow_python_job.rb` and add `python3 /app/jobs/script.py` in the `perform` function
4. In the controller's method you want it to run add `SlowPythonJob.perform_later`

Now when you open that controllers action in the browser it will queue the job and run it in the background while running the rest of the action immediately. ActiveJob also lets you run `SlowPythonJob.perform_now` which will run the job and wait for it to finish before running the rest of the action.

What all that does is tell rails to execute the perform method of SlowPythonJob through the `Active Job Async Job` queue adapter. This works well for the development environment. Keep in mind you will have to set up another queue adapter to handle the job queue in production since `Active Job Async Job` will drop all the jobs if there is a crash... and it isn't as fast or has as many features as the other ones.

Here is a list of queue adapters: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html

Comment: For the perform function, do you suggest putting 'python3 /app/jobs/script.py' in tickmarks? They don't work without something like that.

Comment: system, `` and Open3 should all work. I think Open3 is better since you could read the the err, out and st to see if it ran as it should. running it with `` won't tell you there was an error

Comment: Unfortunately none of this works. When the job is called, it seems to take over the Rails server and the server stops doing anything else.

Comment: how are you calling the `SlowPythonJob` in the controller? Are you sure you don't have a call to the script directly somewhere else? ActiveJob will run the script in its own separate process if you are calling `perform_later`